# Calling overloaded methods using generics

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

I have a class which has a number of overloaded methods:

```
public class CustomerCommandHandlers 
{

    public void Handler(ChangeNameCommand command)
    {
      ...
    }

    public void Handler(ChangeAddressCommand command)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

I have included the following method:

```
    public void Handle<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        Handler((dynamic)command);
    }
```

which allows me to call the overloaded methods from another class that registers the command and the command handler.

However, as I create other commandHandlers such as ProductCommandHandlers, InventoryCommandHandlers etc, I do not want to include the dynamic method in each class.

Is there a way I can create a base class for every command handler which contains this method and then I can call this method from the base class?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already using dynamics, you might as well try this as a base class:

```
public class Basehandler 
{
    public void Handle<TCommand>(T command) where TCommand : ICommand {
        ((dynamic)this).Handler(command);
    }

    // As fallback if there is no implementation for the command type
    public void Handler(ICommand val) {
        // You could implement default or error handling here.
        Console.WriteLine(val == null ? "null" : val.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Exactly what I was looking for. What is the fallback for?

Comment: well since it's using dynamic, you can't be sure if there is an implementation for the type of the parameter. If you would pass some CommandThatYouHaveNoHandlerFor, you would get a RuntimeBinderException. Either you handle that, or you use a Fallback Handler to implement your own default handling.  

EDIT: Modified the answer to match your example better